# Transpose Bureau Data - Issue The ID value "'dd/mm/yyyy'n" occurs twice in the same BY group

Tags: sas, duplicates, transpose

I am trying to transpose bureau data which is in text format from long to wide, however i am facing below error

ERROR: The ID value "'03/09/2019'n" occurs twice in the same BY group.
ERROR:

[image]PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.delq_wkl5 OUT=delq_wkl6 (DROP= *NAME* *LABEL*);

BY LOAN_NUMBER;

VAR DPD;

ID RPTDTE;

RUN;

Comment: I don't get said error with the example data provided.  The error is quite descriptive, so you should read it and understand what it means.  Please provide example data (in text, not picture form) that reproduces the error if you still need help.

Comment: Hi Joe I am new to this platform, let me try and attach the date in text format once I am back home from. Work. The example data is just 3 rows, which is not representative of the entire data, shall. share the same